# How do you get the individual outputs of grep?

Tags: awk, grep, html

I've seen grep thrown around in plenty of answers but never wrapped my head around it.

Now that I am playing with trying to get the content within HTML tags of a locally saved page from the internet, I've hit a wall. I can get grep to identify the output I want, but not a damn chance at having it delimited to be usable.

This is my test.sh file contents:

```
a=$(awk '/<div class="power-bar-text">/,/<\/div>/' 'Acid Fast.html')
b=$(echo $a | grep -PzTo [0-9\.]+)
echo $a
echo $b
```

Results in this terminal output:

```
test.sh: line 4: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
<div class="power-bar-text"> 9 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 8 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 11.25 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 10 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 6 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 5 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 2 (1s) </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 3 </div> <div class="power-bar-text"> 2.50 </div>
9811.2510652132.50
```

Here is a previous iteration that had slightly better human readability:

```
$ awk '/<div class="power-bar-text">/,/<\/div>/' 'Acid Fast.html' | grep -Pzn -C1 [0-9\.]+ -
1:            <div class="power-bar-text">
                9
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                8
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                11.25
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                10
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                2 (1s)
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="power-bar-text">
                2.50
            </div>
```

I don't know how to set up coloring in the code box above, but the terminal does code it with default matching font color red for every digit and period there.

(This would probably not work if the class names happened to be "power.bar.text" because the period would match there... So any assistance on making sure any period is a digit? I guess that could be `[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*` for the regex.)

But going back to that first code block using the code from the bash, the final output it provides is `9811.2510652132.50`. But I want something like `9,8,11.25,10,6,5,2,1,3,2.50`

If I were to have coded grep, I would have had a `-d,` option to set up the delimiter as a command in the output. Unfortunately, that idea didn't work when I tried it.

One terrible idea I had that may work is using the -m parameter output to process it repeatedly, incrementing the number of matches allowed, and then find what is new between each output. Again, that sounds terrible. (E.g. I expect -m1 would get me 9, then -m2 would get me 98, and -m3 would get me 9811.25 and I would "subtract" m2's output from m1's output to be the 8; m3's output from m2's output to get the 11.25.)

And actually having just tried that, it does NOT work because I guess awk makes it a single line so no matter how many matches I limit it to, the full string of `9811.2510652132.50` is output, because the entirety of it is the first and only match.

Surely there is a better way?

Comment: If I am totally on the wrong track for managing this in bash, I am open to a better idea on how to get those numbers out of the HTML file. They are surrounded by div tags, as shown in the awk output. (Awk seems to get it narrowed down to visually what I want, but it looks like the problem may be it produces a single string output that messes with grep.)

Comment: well, with `-z`, you're explicitly asking it to use the NUL byte as delimiter, so you should probably look into what you're doing with that.

Comment: Have you read the [grep man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)? Can you explain why you use all of those flags - `-PzTo`? My guess is that you just took them from some irrelevant example without trying to understand their meaning. Begin by reading about those flags and eliminating those you don't need (probably all).

Comment: So, that's a high effort question! Good on you for asking it. However, grep is not a sufficiently advanced tool to actually understand HTML, which is not a regular language. [One of my favorite stackoverflow answers was written by someone who might have had to explain that a couple of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). What you can do is use a different tool than grep!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, though as they say in [comments to some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment16523188_1733489) there, scraping has its upsides. Not sure if the web has turned better in that sense in 10 years, though...

Comment: @ilkkachu sure, if you can restrict your input enough that a regular expression catches all the things you're interested in, it's going to be much faster at parsing. However, I feel that OP probably doesn't have to process tens of thousands of documents per second, especially with a bash approach :) I do however caution that the comment you linked to was "I had input that was decidedly *not* valid HTML, so my HTML tools broke down" – which I think isn't that surprising :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, of course. Just that we can't always decide what the input is going to be. (And HTML at least used to be written and interpreted really sloppily...)

Comment: @ilkkachu Let me assure you, "a mess" is a very generous term for modern HTML in the wild, still.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, happy to know that! (no, waiit...)

Comment: @ilkkachu :D :D :D but at least our browsers got much much better at dealing with inconsistencies

Comment: @ikkachu the -Pz was what I found to allow matching multiple lines. Without it, no match comes up for an opening <div> and a closing </div> tag because they are on different lines. T was my hope at a tab delimited output, but that didn't work. o was my attempt at just getting the numbers, which works but they all concatenate. `b=$(echo $a | grep [0-9\.]+)` with zero flags outputs nothing, the b value is set to null. But yes! Just -Po is all I need. Every multiline example never explained what the Z did; but my output in $b becomes 9 8 11.25 10 6 5 2 1 3 2.50 w/ b=$(echo $a | grep -Po [0-9\.]+)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I like the effort of that post, but it seems incorrect as I have definitely used regex, albeit it sillyly, to scrape html documents before. The trick is having a language that outputs a position command to let you know where it found a hit, and then having another command start searching for the next needle from that position. I've used that plenty of times with the windows autohotkey implementation. I almost explored that path as grep does have a b output, but I had to explore other commands like cut I guess to work with just that chunk.

Comment: @Tim50001 if you have something that "understands" enough structure to give a position – sure. But in the example here, perfectly valid HTML could contain all the things you grep for in comments, embedded javascript, just as CDATA, …. You would also need to respect that HTML allows for arbitrary amount of whitespace in your tags, additional unused attributes, line breaks, …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As mentioned in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/741068/how-do-you-get-the-individual-outputs-of-grep/741070#comment1407726_741068), `grep` (a utility for extracting lines from unstructured text documents) is not a tool you want to use for parsing HTML, or structured documents in general.  Ideally, you want to use a tool capable of applying structured queries against the document to extract, modify, or process the data in other ways.  For XML documents, one such command-line tool is `xmlstarlet`, with which you may apply [XPath queries](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to XML documents.

Assuming your HTML document is proper XHTML, we can extract the contents of the `div` nodes that have `class` attributes with the value `power-bar-text`, while at the same time trimming off flanking whitespace:

```bash
xmlstarlet select --template \
    --match '//div[@class="power-bar-text"]' \
    --value-of 'normalize-space()' -nl file.xml
```

This first matches the `div` nodes we are interested in and then pulls out the result of the `normalize-space()` function applied to these matched nodes. At the end, the `-nl` delimits each output with a newline character.

Or, using short options,

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m '//div[@class="power-bar-text"]' \
    -v 'normalize-space()' -n file.xml
```

Given the document fragment that you show, this would probably output something like the following:

```
9
8
11.25
10
6
5
2 (1s)
3
2.50
```

This could be put on a single line with commas as delimiters by passing it through

```bash
paste -d , -s -
```

... like so:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//div[@class="power-bar-text"]' -v 'normalize-space()' -n file.xml | paste -d , -s -
9,8,11.25,10,6,5,2 (1s),3,2.50
```

Add some extra processing if you only want whatever occurs before the first space on each line of output from the `xmlstarlet` command:

```bash
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//div[@class="power-bar-text"]' -v 'normalize-space()' -n file.xml | sed 's/ .*//' | paste -d , -s -
9,8,11.25,10,6,5,2,3,2.50
```

---

If your file is not XHTML, you may potentially convert it into something usable using

```bash
xmlstarlet format --recover --html file.html >file.xml
```

Comment: This works, as expected it outputs the values I was looking for after converting to the .xml file (thank goodness that function exists as it threw only about 80 errors for the raw .html file) and may give me some more power in helping match adjacent nodes together with some playing around with this code to figure out how it works. But it seems straight forward. I figure I can break it apart into arrays based on previous html questions I've seen, so thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To add to Kusalananda's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741070/106650), if you have more general HTML, you might want to use BeautifulSoup instead of hoping to to convert to XML (not that it doesn't use different XML parsers itself under the hood, the way it deals with parsing might just be more graceful for your use case).

You'd write a script – but not a `bash` script, but a Python script (this is written straight from the top of my head and only superficially tested)

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

if not len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print(
        f"expected one argument, got {len(sys.argv) - 1}:\n {' '.join(sys.argv)}",
        file=sys.stderr,
    )
    sys.exit(-1)

with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(inputfile)

hits = soup.find_all("div", class_="power-bar-text")

for hit in hits:
    content = hit.contents[0].strip()
    print(f"found value {content}")
```

Save to some file, say `myparser.py`, make executable (`chmod 755 myparser.py`), and run with the HTML file name as argument (`/path/to/myparser.py /path/to/input.html`).

So much for the pretty, self-explanative code. Should you feel the need to do this in your shell, you can condense it to a one-liner. (I'd recommend you don't do that; you can embed the full well-readable, sensible-error-generating python code above in your bash script in a multiline string/HEREDOC, instead):

```bash
infile="foo.html"
python3 -c "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS;soup=BS(open('${infile}'));print('\n'.join(tag.contents[0].strip() for tag in soup.find_all('div', class_='power-bar-text')))"
```

Comment: I need to research this answer because apparently I don't have module bs4, so copy and pasting the script throws an error on line 3 for me. Figuring out html parsing could be great, but I don't know if I'm ready to take on python yet. The syntax is so much more sensible than bash so I'm going to inevitably confuse the two. (spaces around equal signs for value assignment to variable for one). This will definitely be for if I circle back on larger projects that benefit from a more elegant solution. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what system you're on, but it it's debian or a descendant, `sudo apt install python3-bs4`; if on Fedora or similar, `sudo dnf install python3-beautifulsoup4 `.

Comment: Thanks. I had python3 installed, didn't realize there will be derivatives to install too.